# Recurring Profiles with Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing

Tags: authorize.net

I've read that Recurring Profiles only work with Paypal. However Authorize.net has an add on service called "Automated Recurring Billing" which is a tool for submitting and managing recurring, or subscription-based, transactions. http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/automatedrecurringbilling/

I'm wondering what needs to be setup for this to work with Magento's Recurring Profiles?

Comment: Why not go with Braintree?  Their api is better and I think generally their rates are pretty competitive. There is at least one recurring module out there for it.

Comment: Does Braintree allow my customers to still purchase products through magento? @kalenjordan

Comment: Yes, they're a payment gateway just like authorize.net.

Comment: @kalenjordan I guess the only reason is because this would cause us to have 2 gateways. Authorize.net and Braintree.

Comment: Sure, you wouldn't want to have two.  What I meant to suggest was that you switch from Auth.net to Braintree.  I think they have a stronger offering all around, but I'm probably a bit biased.

Answer (score 2):

Magento Recurring Profiles are built with the Paypal recurring profile in mind - though in recent releases they've made the branding less apparent. Out of the box this doesn't work with other payment methods but the development is open-ended enough as to be able to plug in with a 3rd party module.

There are a number of paid and free/open-source modules available to achieve similar results with Authorize. Here is one such plugin:

https://github.com/tegansnyder/Magento-Programmatically-Create-Recurring-Profiles-Authorize.net-CIM.

Some others are available with a simple Google search:

http://blog.gorillagroup.com/creating-subscription-based-and-recurring-payments-with-magento-enterprise/

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/authorize-net-cim-payment-module-with-recurring-profiles-8404.html

**Something completely different:**

Check out some 3rd party services like http://recurly.com/ and http://www.ordergroove.com/

Comment: thanks! Anyone you recommend more over another? We're mostly looking to be able to process paypal and authorize.net

Comment: The gorilla module is a class A module for CIM management in my opinion. Highly recommended.

Comment: thanks so much for all your help. Would the CIM mean it wouldn't work for the Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing (ARB)?  @philwinkle

Comment: I believe that the ARB uses CIM as a storage method. But I'm no expert. Probably talk with Gorilla support.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out and let you know. Both of the links in the Gorilla group article lead to a 404 error page... any ideas? Is this it http://instore.gorillagroup.com/magento-extensions/authorize-net-cim-extension  @philwinkle

Comment: All of the links you recommended either require a pricey extension in order to work or they are just the pricey extension. Is there any point of Magento even having the Recurring Profiles if they can't even function with-out an expensive extension? @philwinkle

Comment: There is no free solution here that I know of. It costs money to make money, unfortunately. The good news is you have a $180 Million ecommerce platform *for free*. So hopefully that's some comfort!

Answer (score 0):

There is a magento module by Salesignitor which supports Paypal and Authorize.net both out of the box. I have it installed on my store. However in my case I want it to accept INR and neither of the two payment methods support it. But it could be useful for you.

Have a look:

http://www.rental-e-commerce-software.com/reservation-system-features.php

Answer (score 0):

Check out these these plugins. The may interest you:

http://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/magento-authorize-net-zahlungs-extension.html

http://www.sellxed.com/shop/en/magento-subscription-manager.html

They work very well and support the named features.