# Recurring payment method

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-gateway, recurring

I already asked this question on stackoverflow but no replies. Neither did I find a useful reply to this issue on the web! So I am asking it here again.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983505/recurring-profile-magento-payment-gateway-india

I want to use any payment gateway which can accept recurring profile payment from a magento store in INR. Please do not suggest paypal as it won't work in our case.

My requirements are clear:

```
I just want to confirm the transaction for a product which has recurring profile. So the payment gateway should accept the parameters for a recurring payment.

I do NOT want recurring payments(deductions from the account each month)
```

Right now, I have integrated EBS payment gateway successfully into my store and made modifications into it so that the payment method shows up during checkout.

However, after I click place order, the purchase is successful and the user is not redirected to EBS (just for the products with recurring profile).

Please reply. Even a minor help could be much fruitful for me. Many thanks viewers

Comment: see this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/recurring-profiles-with-authorize-net-automated-recurring-billing

Comment: I had to use a workaround where recurring profile products are purchased using offline payments!

Comment: The reason you are not getting answered is becuase there is no real answer to this, other than the fact that you need a recurring profile capable payment method module, which ties in with a payment gateway that supports recurring profiles. The post I pointed out mentions a few of those. There is no 'easy fix' and as you may already have heard, magento only supports recurring profiles via paypal, out the box.

Comment: Nevermind. I already have an answer on that post.  I am not expecting an answer now as I've found a workaround and the site is live.

Comment: Could you post an answer to the question if you feel it could help another person out?

Comment: @DavidManners As I said, its not a solution to the above problem, its just a workaround. Recurring payments don't work here in India. We, instead of using online payments, used offline payment for recurring profile items, which does work. Link to the plugin I used(salesignitor) is in my answer to another post.. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/recurring-profiles-with-authorize-net-automated-recurring-billing