# Custom first shipment in recurring order

Tags: shipping, api, recurring

I have task to create a custom shipment for recurring order.  We sell strips that customer will use every month so we set a recurring product for this.  For the first month we want to deliver strips and device and for all other months we want to send strips only.

Also we want for user to go through checkout process only once.  So he is buying recurring product and nothing else. and as a result first month he has strips with device and only strips for all other months.

One more, We use fulfilment company for our shipment needs.  This company uses Magento API to get information about orders.  Through the API for the first month we need to send this company request to send SKUStripsAndDevice product to customer 1 and next months we want to send SKUStrips product.

Any ideas how to implement it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7033788/can-i-detect-if-a-magento-function-is-being-run-as-an-api-call
has a code how to find if magento runs on API call.  I was thinking I will change SKU for the first month in recurring order details if request is in API mode.

Any ideas, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I currently have not work with recurring payment in magento  but if you take a look at [Working with Recurring Profiles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/working-with-recurring-profiles)

You could try

- create the "device" as a Simple product
- create the "strips" as a Recurring Profiles

Then try to create a bundled item or auto add to cart 'strips' when someone add a 'device'

See [Recurring Profile and Bundled Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320877/recurring-profile-and-bundled-item)

Then take a look at the total that set for recurring payment, if the total is less device amount else search for the code that set recurring payment amount

Also see [Recurring Profiles with Authorize.net Automated Recurring Billing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7533/recurring-profiles-with-authorize-net-automated-recurring-billing)